# Scala TraversableOnce and toSet

Tags: scala

In **Scala**, why does the following occur when using the `toSet` functionality from `TraversableOnce`?

If you create a worksheet (in IntelliJ) with the following code you will get the following output (NB: using Scala 2.10.2):

```scala
val maps = List(List(1,2),List(3,4),List(5,6,7),List(8),List())

maps.flatMap( _.map( _ +  " " ) )
maps.flatMap( _.map( _ +  " " ) ).toSet
maps.flatMap( _.map( _ +  " " ) ).toSet()
```

i.e. res4 produces a boolean

```scala
> maps: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4), List(5, 6, 7), List(8), List())
> res2: List[String] = List("1 ", "2 ", "3 ", "4 ", "5 ", "6 ", "7 ", "8 ")
> res3: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set("3 ", "8 ", "4 ", "5 ", "1 ", "6 ", "2 ", "7 ")
> res4: Boolean = false
```

Needless to say I was a confused for long enough until I noted `toSet` doesn't use parentheses in the implementation, but why the boolean?

Comment: Looking at compiled bytecode, what actually happens -- resulting set's apply method got called with Unit argument, but can't say why. Looks like a bug, since it is not reproducible if I try to call `()` on res3

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you and others have already noticed, `toSet` doesn't provide a parameter list. Thus, calling it with parentheses, will always result in a compilation error unless the compiler finds an apply method that expects an argument as it is the case in your example:

```
scala> List(1).toSet()
res2: Boolean = false

scala> List(1).toSet.apply()
res3: Boolean = false
```

scalac has a feature called "adapting argument lists", which is visible with `-Xlint`:

```
scala> List(1).toSet()
<console>:8: warning: Adapting argument list by inserting (): this is unlikely to be what you want.
        signature: GenSetLike.apply(elem: A): Boolean
  given arguments: <none>
 after adaptation: GenSetLike((): Unit)
              List(1).toSet()
                           ^
res7: Boolean = false
```

scalac tries to wrap the argument into a tuple, as one can see in the [sources](https://github.com/sschaef/scala/blob/master/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Typers.scala#L3268) (where an empty argument list will be treated as the `Unit` literal by [`gen.mkTuple`](https://github.com/sschaef/scala/blob/master/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/TreeGen.scala#L285)):

```
      /* Try packing all arguments into a Tuple and apply `fun`
       * to that. This is the last thing which is tried (after
       * default arguments)
       */
      def tryTupleApply: Tree = (
        if (eligibleForTupleConversion(paramTypes, argslen) && !phase.erasedTypes) {
          val tupleArgs = List(atPos(tree.pos.makeTransparent)(gen.mkTuple(args)))
          // expected one argument, but got 0 or >1 ==> try applying to tuple
          // the inner "doTypedApply" does "extractUndetparams" => restore when it fails
          val savedUndetparams = context.undetparams
          silent(_.doTypedApply(tree, fun, tupleArgs, mode, pt)) map { t =>
              // Depending on user options, may warn or error here if
              // a Unit or tuple was inserted.
              val keepTree = (
                   !mode.typingExprNotFun
                || t.symbol == null
                || checkValidAdaptation(t, args)
              )
              if (keepTree) t else EmptyTree
          } orElse { _ => context.undetparams = savedUndetparams ; EmptyTree }
        }
        else EmptyTree
      )
```

Which btw, is a feature that is [not mentioned in the spec](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3583). Adding the parentheses explicitly will let the warning go away:

```
scala> List(1).toSet(())
res8: Boolean = false
```

One remaining question now is why the code above does not produce a compilation error due to the fact that the list is of type `List[Int]` and the apply method of `Set` has type signature `apply(A): Boolean`, thus expects an `Int` in our case. The reason for this is a [very well known problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544536/type-inference-on-set-failing) and a result of the type signature of `toSet` which is `toSet[B >: A]: Set[B]`. The type signature denotes a lower bound, which means that any supertype of `Int` can be passed as argument.

Because in our case `Unit` is specified as the type of the argument, the compiler has to search for a common supertype of `Unit` and `Int` that matches the type signature of `toSet`. And because there is such a type, namely `AnyVal`, the compiler will infer that type and going forward without falling apart with an error:

```
scala> List(1).toSet[AnyVal](())
res9: Boolean = false
```

Comment: Bravo! The beast with ( horns ) is slain!

Comment: That _really_ should be in the spec - consider [voting](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3583).

Comment: Nice explanation, but no answer is complete without a reference to the puzzler.  http://scalapuzzlers.com/#pzzlr-040 and related http://scalapuzzlers.com/#pzzlr-036 and http://scalapuzzlers.com/#pzzlr-032, OK, basically every puzzler.  Maybe there is a meta-puzzler that covers every edge case in the language.

Comment: @som-snytt: btw, hearing from you here right now, I remember that you should take a look to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895467/why-cant-be-used-inside-of-string-interpolation) and especially to my answer...