# Scala String Interpolation with Underscore

Tags: scala, string-interpolation, scala-2.11, apache-spark-2.2

I am new to Scala so feel free to point me in the direction of documentation but I was not able to find an answer to this question in my research.

I am using *scala 2.11.8 with Spark2.2* and trying to create a dynamic string containing dateString1_dateString2 (with underscores) using interpolation but having some issues.

```
val startDt = "20180405" 
val endDt = "20180505"
```

This seems to work:

```
s"$startDt$endDt"
res62: String = 2018040520180505
```

But this fails:

```
s"$startDt_$endDt"
<console>:27: error: not found: value startDt_
       s"$startDt_$endDt"
          ^
```

I expected this simple workaround with escapes to work but does not produce desired results:

```
s"$startDt\\_$endDt"
res2: String = 20180405\_20180505
```

Note that this question differs from [Why can't _ be used inside of string interpolation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895467/why-cant-be-used-inside-of-string-interpolation) in that this question is looking to find a workable string interpolation solution while the previous question is much more internals-of-scala focused.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't \_ be used inside of string interpolation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895467/why-cant-be-used-inside-of-string-interpolation)

Comment: Did you try to use raw interpolation?

Comment: s"${startDt}_${endDt}"

Comment: @RamanMishra I don't think it is a duplicate of that question. That question is about using the _ anonymous placeholder parameter. This is about smashing _ at the end of a $ variable and looking up another.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can be explicit using curly braces:

```
@ s"${startDt}_${endDt}"
res11: String = "20180405_20180505"
```

Your code:

```
s"$startDt_$endDt"
```

fails since `startDt_` is a valid identifier, and scala tries to interpolate that non-existant variable.

Comment: Yes, this does compile but does not produce the required results:
`val startDt_ = "20180405"
val endDt = "20180505"
s"$startDt_$endDt"
res13: String = 2018040520180505`

Comment: @user9074332 yes, because in that case, the `_` is part of the variable name, but you want a literal `_` character in your string.

Comment: @user9074332 my point was "that's what the error means" (it's looking up the variable `startDt_`). :)